# boot normally even with an infinite loop in /etc/rc.local

Tags: shell, rc

I put a python script with an infinite loop into `/etc/rc.local` but the machine boots successfully, which confuses me.

The `/etc/rc.local` content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/home/pi/py/startsignal.py &
/home/pi/py/fan.py
touch /home/pi/thisisrun
exit 0
```

**startsignal.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(18, 1)
```

**fan.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
upper_temp = 55
lower_temp = 45
# minutes
check_interval = 2

def get_temp():
    with open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp', 'r') as f:
        temp = float(f.read()) / 1000
    return temp

def check_temp():
    if get_temp() > upper_temp:
        gpio.setup(23, gpio.OUT)
    elif get_temp() < lower_temp:
        gpio.setup(23, gpio.IN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # check every 2 minutes
    try:
        while True:
            check_temp()
            sleep(check_interval * 60)
    finally:
        gpio.cleanup()
```

All the code relevant is above. I thought about this after googling around.

1. the `#!/bin/sh -e` indicates that the script will exit once an error occurs.
2. the `/home/pi/thisisrun` file is not created, so there must be an error above this line
3. after booting into system I can see that `fan.py` is running. So I guess the error occurs during the execution of `fan.py`. But the `fan.py` has an infinite loop in it !

How can a python script generates an error but still runs normally?

How can `/bin/sh` detects the error when the `fan.py` never returns?

OS: raspbian stretch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Raspbian Stretch uses `systemd` like regular Debian Stretch does by default, `/etc/rc.local` is started by `/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service`:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

# This unit gets pulled automatically into multi-user.target by
# systemd-rc-local-generator if /etc/rc.local is executable.
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.local
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=yes
GuessMainPID=no
```

As it specifies `Type=forking`, `TimeoutSec=0` and `RemainAfterExit=yes`, I understand that systemd basically starts it and does not care whether it exits or not. So that explains why the system can successfully complete the boot even if `/etc/rc.local` is still running.

Your `rc.local` script first runs `startsignal.py` in the background (= with the `&`): that means only a failure to start the script would cause an error in the `rc.local` script at that point. If `startsignal.py` successfully starts but then returns an error, `rc.local` would have to use `wait <process or job ID>` to read the incoming error from the `startsignal.py` process. But your process apparently does not care to check for that.

Then your `rc.local` starts `fan.py`. Since it is started without `&`, the shell will start another process to run `fan.py` and wait for it to exit... but since `fan.py` has an infinite loop, it will not exit until the system is being shut down, `fan.py` has an error, or the process running `fan.py` is killed. The `touch /home/pi/thisisrun` will be executed only after `fan.py` has exited.

I think it would make more sense to start `startsignal.py` **without** the `&` and `fan.py` **with** it, rather than vice versa.

Comment: I did an experiment in CentOS7 by putting a py script (*foreground, also has an infinite loop in it*) in rc.local and the rc-local service is the same except the dir of rc.local is /etc/rc.d/rc.local. This time the system won't boot. Both CentOS7  and Stretch use systemd use systemd and the same config. Care to explain this?

Comment: OK, then please add `set -x` as the first non-comment line in `rc.local`. Then you'll see what actually gets executed by the script, either as on-screen messages at boot time, or with `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=rc-local.service` later. Also note that Debian has a drop-in file that modifies the rc-local.service: use `systemctl cat rc-local.service` to see the full service definition that is actually in effect.